# Outputting a html <option> tag with a php for loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop

New to php and html so the ideas are very basic. I have been asked to use a basic for loop in php to output the `<option>` elements from html. Since the `<option>` elements are not variables, how do I print them?

```
<select name="server" class="form-control">
              <option>Server 1</option>
              <option>Server 2</option>
              <option>Server 3</option>
              <option>Server 4</option>
              <option>Server 5</option>
<?php
    int $i;
    for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++)
        {

        echo $i+1; 
        }
 ?>
```

Comment: `echo "<option>Server $i</option>";` maybe...

Comment: are the example options (i.e. `Server1-5`) what you need to generate? or do you need to generate other options, with various `id` and/or `value` attributes?

Comment: Also, `int $i;` is not PHP.

Comment: Also, also, maybe `for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)`

Comment: I'm confused, what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to use PHP to read the HTML, or write the HTML?

Comment: Honestly idk what he wants, it is for a school assignment. We were given an html document and told to turn it into a php document. The instructions straight from the assignment says, "Use a for loop to output the <options> elements."

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
    <select name="server" class="form-control">
     <?php for($i =1; $i <= 5; ++$i){
       echo "<option>Server $i</option>";
      } ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: This is for a school assignment, so I don't think just handing out the solution to the OP is a good idea. We should be educating them rather.